# scroll to the bottom of a page

Tags: jquery

The problem I am facing is that ,I have a set of questions in my survey . The first question asks the user to click on the check box if he is not a member . If the user selects the check box the cursor should automatically scroll to the bottom of the page skipping all the questions that comes after it .

I have tried different functions using jquery but none worked .
This is the code which I tried previously (P.S neither did this work)

```
  <?php
    if(!stristr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"printSummary")) {
        require_once("../lib/include/common.inc.php");
    } else {
        require_once("../../lib/include/common.inc.php");
    }
    ob_start();

    $node_id = $parentnode?$parentnode:getDataFromSession("data,node_id");
    $node_name = get_node_name( $node_id,$_SESSION["survey"],$_SESSION['idLink']);
    $surveyForText = getText2("This survey is for:")." ".$node_name;

    if(strlen($node_name)>0) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
        echo "$('.generalErrorMsg').first().addClass('generalErrorMsgWithMargin').text(\"$surveyForText\");";
        echo "});";
        echo "</script>";
    }
 //code that I am talking about starts here
    $currentPageNum = currentPageNumber();
    if($currentPageNum==4)
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
                alert('here');
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    window.scrollTo(0, 1) },100);
            }); 


            //window.scrollBy(100,100); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
            //scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',80); // scrolls every 80 milliseconds
        });";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    ?>
```

Please help me with the resolution code. Thanks in advance
-Jathin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```
scrollTop.
```

`scrollTop` is a property of `DOM Object`.

but in jQuery have a function scrollTop() for that, so you can use in jquery.

like `$(window).scrollTop(100);`

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
   alert('here');
   setTimeout(function() { 
      window.scrollTo(0, 1) },100);
});
```

change to

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
   //alert('here');
   setTimeout(function() { 
      $(window).scrollTop(100);},100);
});
```

and if you have an element where to scroll
you can try with

```
$(window.)scrollTop($('#elemenet-id').offset().top);
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle to check?.

Answer (score 0):

your code is hard to read because of the mixture of php,html and javascript
you'd better show only final html+javascript.
anyway if you need to scroll window to the footer of document - `$(document).scrollTop($(document).height())`